# Pyspark : Create columns from an dataframe column containing dynamic nested JSON string

Tags: python, pyspark

I have Below dataframe :

```
Id        data          
1         {"A":{"S":{"m":1,"v":9.0,"p":2.0},"U":{"m":0,"c":8.0,"b":3.9}}}
```

Final dataframe to looklike::

```
Id    A.S.m   A.S.v   A.S.p   A.U.m   A.U.c   A.U.b  
1     1       9.0     2.0      0       8.0     3.9
```

How can i achieve it using pyspark.

Comment: Is your structure always the same?

Comment: No...it is dynamic...